# Does this comment from Stephen Cook on p-np problem has support from others?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, np-complete

It is kind of odd to ask for a credibility of a comment from someone who invented the field, but let me introduce one of Stephen Cook's comments supposing when the situation comes out as p=np.

"... it would transform mathematics by allowing a computer to find a formal proof of any theorem which has a proof of a reasonable length, since formal proofs can easily be recognized in polynomial time. Example problems may well include all of the CMI prize problems." [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Consequences_of_solution)

I've always thought [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) imply that an automatic machine which verifies the proof of every mathematical statement under any kind of consistent formal system is impossible.

Were my thoughts wrong? Or if I was not wrong, then what was Stephen Cook trying to say with his words?

I may guess, he was trying to insist that an automatic proof machine under some restricted conditions might be possible, only if when there is some effective solution to p=np.

Or there can be some another interpretation that he was premising 'verifying proof' and 'finding proof' are different in nature. However it arises a question that how can a machine 'find a proof' if it can't 'verify a proof'.

Could someone explain me the meaning of the comment from Stephen Cook? Thanks.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: Ohhh I see. Then can I understand that the purpose for finding a formal proof with some 'effective p=np machine' is to find some easier proofs of some mathematical theorems which already have some proofs?

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: Wow, then it is two-way approach to attack a problem! Awesome!!!!

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: Oh yes please turn them to the answer.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: If I don't bother you I would like to ask some off-topic questions on mathematical logic. Since it is quite a rare chance for me to encounter a professional on the field! How is mathematical logic related to analytic philosophy these days? Are they walking their own separate ways? Or do they submit papers to each other's journals??

Comment: For instance, many books of philosophy deal with Russel and Frege and Gödel. Also in mid of 20th century Putnam and Quine did contribute to mathematics too. As I know Chomsky's theory on his Syntactic Structures influenced some theory on math,,, which I forgot. So for an outsider like me, it is curious what criteria are there to distinguish between analytic philosophy and mathematical logic.

Comment: In modern days, Alain Badiou studies set theory, and Kripke is also well known for his mathematics. So I guess mathematical logicians and analytic philosophers can work together with same topic. I wonder whether I am right.

Comment: It would be best to post this as a new question, there are many logicians on this site.

Comment: @Couchy: Yeah, maybe next time. That is, I first didn't expect some lengthy opinion with the off-topic question, but maybe someone might find it helpful as some open question. I will think about your suggestion.

Comment: @user281 Your question is too long to answer in the comments. I agree with Couchy  that you could post it as a new question. But first, search for related questions on this site and on Philosophy Stackexchange. Questions come up often there about the relationship between mathematics, philosophy, mathematical logic, and philosophical logic.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Sure! I will definitely follow your advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key part of the quote that you're missing is "any theorem which has a proof of a reasonable length". Gödel's theorems imply that there are mathematical statements  for which we can cannot prove  or ¬. Cook's comment applies only to statements  which do admit proofs, and moreover proofs "of a reasonable length".

Fix some polynomial $p$, and a polynomial time enumeration of mathematical statements, and consider the question $Q_p(n)$: "does statement $n$ admit a proof of length at most $p(n)$?" A "yes" answer to $Q_p(n)$ is witnessed by a proof of statement $n$ of length at most $p(n)$. Now there is a polynomial time algorithm to verify proofs of polynomially  bounded length, so there is an NP algorithm to answer question $Q_p$. Thus if P=NP, there is a polynomial time algorithm to answer question $Q_p$, for any fixed polynomial $p$.

Note that a "no" answer to question $Q_p(n)$ tells us nothing. Maybe statement $n$ is provable, but the shortest proof is longer than $p(n)$. Or maybe statement $n$ is provably false, or even independent of ZFC. So the way we would use the algorithm is to guess a polynomial $p$, use as input a statement $n$ we're interested in, and hope that we get a "yes" answer: that statement $n$ has a proof of length at most $p(n)$. We could, in theory, use this method to settle open questions: there are mathematical statements (which we hope include the CMI prize problems!) which admit proofs of a reasonable length, but we haven't found these proofs yet.

However, it's not totally clear that such a method would transform mathematics, as Cook suggests. For one thing, the algorithm might give us a "yes" answer to $Q_p(n)$ without actually constructing a proof. The idea of accepting a computational answer promising that a proof of statement $n$ exists as a valid substitute for an "actual" proof of statement $n$ would no doubt be very controversial (see, e.g. the controversies around computer-assisted proofs of theorems like the four color theorem).

Secondly, as a practical matter, it's quite possible that the polynomial time algorithm solving problem $Q_p$ might run in time $O(x^N)$, where $N$ is much much much larger than the degree of $p$. The result of this might be that we could tractably detect whether statements admit very short proofs, but the algorithm is not actually  feasible  in practice for interesting  inputs.

Comment: How can I expect a better answer than this? Thanks!!!!